# no value given for one or more required parameters. oledb c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

I have created a simple login (C# Windows Forms) with MS Access Database(2016), but when I tried to log in, in the username field if I enter uppercase or lowercase letters its given a successful login.Then after that I used COLLATE in my SELECT query to avoid this error, but after this its always given "no value given for one or more parameters" error

```cs
string username = textBox1.Text.Trim();
string password = textBox2.Text.Trim();

try
{
    if (username == "" || password == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill All Credentials to Login !", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        return;
    }

    db.OpenConnection();
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter(" SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE [username = '" + username + "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS] AND [password = '" + password + "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS] ", db.con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "tblusers");
    db.CloseConnection();

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name or Password! Please Check Your Credentials!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        this.Hide();
        frmDashboard dashboard = new frmDashboard();
        dashboard.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/). You should use parameterized queries instead. And: NEVER store passwords in plain in a database. Use salted hashes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the `COLLATE` clause in your SQL query, which **is specific to SQL Server** and **not supported by MS Access**.

In MS Access, you can use the `StrComp` function to perform a case-sensitive search. To modify your code, update your `OleDbDataAdapter` query to use `StrComp` instead of `COLLATE`.

```cs
da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE StrComp([username], '" + username + "', 0) = 0 AND StrComp([password], '" + password + "', 0) = 0", db.con);
```